# ExtJS - how can I get a panel to display within another panel (it currently displays a blank screen)?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define('something', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'border',
    constructor: function(config){
        let me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.initConfig(config);

}
});
```

Ok so let's say I'm defining my class as above. Later in my code if I wish to do something like the following within the constructor:

```
                let mainPan = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
                    layout: 'border',
                    items: [
                        something,
                        something else
                    ]
                });

               this.add(mainPan);
```

Is there any way for me to add the mainPan and for it to display correctly? When I try this I basically get a white screen and I think it's due to a nesting issue (having a panel within a panel)?

Comment: There is no problem with having a panel inside another panel. Do you have Layout errors or other kind of error in the console? Does `this` is a reference to your first panel? To debug this kind of layout errors i often try to set a background color to the panels so i can see them: `bodyStyle:{"background-color":"red"}, ` (maybe they are displayed correctly but simply white so you don't see them)

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I have slightly amended the code...I should have mentioned that the second part of my code was within the constructor. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

There is some problems with your implementation while creating your panels.

Here is a defined panel that allows you to add it to others views using "xtype"

```
Ext.define('something', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.something',
        title: 'Inner Panel',
        height: 200,
        border: true,
        style: {
            border: '1px solid black'
        },
    });
```

Here is the code for the second panel using "create" and then adding the first panel by using

> xtype: 'something'

```
let mainPan = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        title: 'Here we are',
        border: true,
        style: {
            border: '1px solid black'
        },
        bodyPadding: 10,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'something'
        }]
    });
```

And here is a link to the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31g5) showing it working using Ext JS 7 and the modern framework.

Comment: I have slightly amended the code...I should have mentioned that the second part of my code was within the constructor. Apologies.

Comment: How does that change impact the solution I've shown? Adding the constructor doesn't change how Ext.define and Ext.create work; nor does it change how to add a panel to a panel.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is a nested panel from one class, I suggest that separate "something" class from the main code, in fact, when you define a class you cant make the nested panel in that way.
also even your code is right anyway, it put in the loop, so the best way is looking at what the class meaning and write new code.

```
Ext.define('something', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'border',
});
Ext.define("mainApp", {
    extend: 'something',
    title: 'Biggest Thing',
    initComponent: function() {
        let me = this;

        let mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            items: [
                Ext.create("something", {
                    title: 'Something'
                }),
                Ext.create("something", {
                    title: 'Something Else'
                })
            ]
        });
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                mainPanel
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```